# SharePoint Purchase Order Tracking

Tags: sharepoint-designer, custom-list, calculated-column

I need to create a Purchase Order tracker.  There are a few parameters that I'm unsure how to account for in building the solution.

- Our system allows multiple items to be ordered under a single PO number (could be 1 item, could be 20+ items - all various types, prices, etc).
- I need to track/count the quantities of the individual items ordered, annually (example - 2 monitors ordered today, 250 total for 2017)
- I need to track the total amount spent by each department, annually.
- All items have fluctuating prices.

I appreciate any help.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I would design it as below

1. Create a Purchase List

   - Field 1 - Order name (You can use the title field for this)
   - Field 2 - Purchase Order # (You can create this value either via custom form or via a workflow
2. Create Order List

   - Field 1 - Lookup to Purchase List Field 2 (This will hold the connection)
   - Field 2 - Department (I am not sure if it belong here or it will be in Purchase, you can move it as desired)
   - Field 3 - Unit Price
   - Field 4 - Quantity
   - Field 5 - Calculated Unit Price * Quantity
   - Field 6 - Order date (Or you can use out of the box Created field)

Extend this structure as desired

Now you can create multiple views to full fill your reporting needs

1. Create a view that is grouped by Purchase Number (Field 1)
2. Create a view that is grouped by Department
3. You can use the Total field from the View settings to Sum (Field 5)

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. But any suggestions for how to handle multiple items?  Example: Todays order may be 20 - 3m patch cords, 30 - 2m patch cords, 3 - cabinets, 5 - APC units - all on 1 order.....but the next order may be only 2 - toners.  Then I need to also have a running total for each item ordered (2 toners ordered today, but 50 ordered in 2017).

Comment: You should have logic in your form to do the data insert by splitting the order.. You can use a custom form and use JSOM to achieve this.. or train the user to split the order and enter through out of the box form..